# What gasPrice to use to deploy contract on congested ethereum mainnet

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, consensys-truffle

I am attempting to deploy a contract onto the Ethereum mainnet, I have specified:

network_id: 1,

provider: infura,

gas: 5000000,

gasPrice: 140

And I continuously get the errors:

```
Error: Contract transaction couldn't be found after 50 blocks
```

or

```
transaction underpriced
```

Is this because the mainnet is so congested, miners are not picking up my transaction within the 50 block period?

What gas/gasPrices have other people successfully used on the mainnet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Andrey's answer, your gas is WAY too low. Historically, you will typically need to pay around 10-20 Gwei to have your transaction mined in an average amount of time. If you can wait 10s of minutes or even hours, you can get away with ~5Gwei. If you need the transaction to execute fast, or if you just want an average transaction time when the network is really congested, you're probably looking at ~40Gwei.

You can programmatically set your gas price based on the median gas price of the most recent mined blocks using `web3.eth.getGasPrice(callback)`. [Source](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgasprice).

Comment: Ok, thank you for this its really helpful, so are the gas and gasLimit parameters set in wei? and not Gwei?

Comment: `gasPrice` is in Wei. All contract coding works at the Wei level. You can use the convenience method `web3.toWei(0.01, 'ether')` to convert ether (in this case, 0.01 ether) to Wei. `gas` is a `BigNumber` internally, but what you have is fine. It will be converted.

Answer (score 3):

You can check current gas price at https://ethgasstation.info/ for example. Note that gas price is usually shown in Gwei. So 21 Gwei is 21000000000 wei or 0.000021 eth.